# How should I test user signup/login with third party library like Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, oauth, cucumber, omniauth

I'm using Rails 3.0.3, Rspec2 , Cucumber , Capybara

How should a scenario look for user signup process , when using the Omniauth gem ?

I mean it doesn't make sense for me to testing this library, I only want to test the whole user registration process of my applications point of view:

- open my root_path # my app
- click on /auth/facebook # my app
- THIS IS THE PART OF OMNIAUTH # not my app, doesn't need testing
- access /auth/facebook/callback # my app
- read user information , compare # my app

What is the good practice to test it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explore using the FakeWeb gem (https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb) to mock up the API addresses and fake responses from them. An example of this use case here http://blog.zerosum.org/2009/7/13/twitter-auth-integration-testing